# How to set conditional in sympy to evaluate the limit expression rather than the normal expression if encountering a discontinuity?

Tags: python, limit, sympy, evaluate, piecewise

I have a function which takes in a 2 column np.array (with each row corresponding to some pair, which I'll call (x,t)), and then evaluate an expression that uses this array. The caveat is that there are occasions where the expression evaluated at an (x, t) pair would give a divide by zero error. Thus, in cases like these, I want to evaluate the limit expression rather than the normal expression: i.e. rather than (x, t) specifically, evaluate at **t --> value that gives discontinuity**, not t **at** the value that gives the discontinuity. An example here, and since sympy doesn't have a sech function, I define it via cosh:

```
def sech(x):
    return sympy.cosh(x)**(-1)

def evaluate(xt_array):
    """
    xt_array = [[x1,t1], [x2,t2] … ]
    """
    k = 0.5 # constant
    sols = np.zeros(xt_array.shape[0])
    for i in range(xt_array.shape[0]):
          sols[i] = sech((k*xt_array[i, 1] - xt_array[i, 0])

    return sols
```

The code in its current form will break if `k*xt_array[i, 1] - xt_array[i, 0]` is zero, because sech(0) results in a divide by zero error. Is there a way to set this up such that when the sech expression is supposed to be zero, you evaluate at the limit expression instead?

The sympy "Piecewise" function seems like it could be a way to do this. However, I don't want to hardcode the value of t that results in `k*t-x=0`. This doesn't seem to work:

```
k = 0.5 # constant
sols = np.zeros(xt_array.shape[0])
for i in range(xt_array.shape[0]):
    p = sympy.Piecewise(sech((k*xt_array[i, 1] - xt_array[i, 0]), k*xt_array[i, 1] - xt_array[i, 0] != 0))
```

This doesn't seem to work, and gives this error: TypeError: FunctionClass object argument after * must be an iterable, not numpy.bool_

Comment: There is a sech function in sympy. The condition in the piecewise needs to be symbolic like `Ne(k*xt_array[i, 1], xt_array[i, 0])`

Comment: So you can do this? `p = sympy.Piecewise(sech((k*xt_array[i, 1] - xt_array[i, 0]), sympy.Ne(k*xt_array[i, 1], xt_array[i, 0]))` How do you ensure that if this condition is satisfied, you evaluate at the limit of t --> xt_array[i, 1] (such as xt_array[:, 1] + epsilon)? Since evaluating at xt_array[i, 1] would give a divide by zero error.

Comment: You can use the `limit` function. There is no problem with evaluating `sech(x)` for real x though. It doesn't have any discontinuities.

Comment: True - well it's only when you have sech(0), because you get a divide by zero error. So, is the third argument you give in this case, the limit one?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean given that `sech(0) = 1/cosh(0) = 1`.